# Ambiguous ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to make a parser for a language where `.` could be concatenation or accessing dictionary value by key e.g.
`"a"."b"` - concatenation of two strings
`foo."some text"` - concatenation of "foo" variable's value and "some text"
`myDict.myKey` - getting value from dictionary "myDict" by key "myKey"
`myDict.(myKey)` - concatenation of two variables with names "myDict" and "myKey"

Below is a sample grammar for concatenation and getting dictionary values:

```
grammar Test;

expr:
                expr DOT NAME           #DictFieldExpr
            |   expr DOT expr           #Concatenation
            |   L_PAREN expr R_PAREN    #WrappedExpr
            |   string                  #StringExpr
            |   NAME                    #VariableExpr
;

string:         QUOTE .*? QUOTE;

NAME:           [a-zA-Z]+;
L_PAREN:        '(';
R_PAREN:        ')';
DOT:            '.';
QUOTE:          '"';
```

As I know `#DictFieldExpr` should have higher priority than `#Concatenation` because it was defined earlier. But for input like `outerDict.innerDict.key` parser returns

```
expr:Concatenation----expr:VariableExpr----NAME:"outerDict"
                  \
                   \
              expr:DictFieldExpr----expr:VariableExpr----NAME:"innerDict"
                            \
                             \NAME:"key"
```

(both nodes should be `DictFieldExpr`, but the first node is taken for `Concatenation` for some reason)
How to handle such ambiguous grammars in ANTLR4?

Comment: (1) Associativity here can be implemented by right-recursion. (2) `QUOTE` should be a fragment as to not allow it to be a token by itself. But, I'd just use the literal directly in `String`, which should be a lexer rule, not parser rule. (3) I'd remove all the alt labeling--clouds the grammar. (4) I'd use `'.'` instead of `DOT`, `'('` instead of `L_PAREN` (less keystrokes), but you can keep the explicit token rules you like. (5) Simplified grammar is `grammar Test; exp: Name '.' exp | '(' exp ')' exp | Str '.' exp | Name | '(' exp ')' | Str; Str: '"' .*? '"'; Name: [a-zA-Z]+;`.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Try this `grammar Test; exp: (Name | '(' exp ')' | Str) '.' exp | (Name | '(' exp ')' | Str); Str: '"' .*? '"'; Name: [a-zA-Z]+;`.

Comment: Alt labeling is necessary for visitors to walk the tree properly, so I can't just merge two rules and simplify the grammar. Grammar should differentiate between concatenation and accessing dictionary value by key and that's the problem

Comment: Alt labeling is never necessary, and it is not here. A better approach I would consider with your grammar is symbol labeling, and it is supported more often than alt labeling in other parser generators. However, both are optimizations. One can distinguish the alts and symbols using probing of the children. For example, to distinguish between the 1st and 2nd alts of the `exp` rule, test the last child. To disambiguate the alts of the groupings in the two rule-level alts, one can test the first child. But, if you want, you could perform two ungrouping refactorings, then label every alt.

Comment: I guess you are right. Making visitor to differentiate this two cases instead of grammar sounds much better. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

(Revised based upon comments)

This seems to work for all of your sample input.  The resulting parse tree is "awkward", but then, so, apparently, is the language syntax :)

(I backed out the changes re: the `string` rule based upon your comment.)

```
grammar Test
    ;
expr
    : expr dictSuffix   # DictFieldExpr
    | expr concatSuffix # Concatenation
    | '(' expr ')'      # WrappedExpr
    | string            # StringExpr
    | NAME              # VariableExpr
    ;

dictSuffix: ('.' NAME)+;
concatSuffix: '.' expr;

string: QUOTE .*? QUOTE;

NAME:    [a-zA-Z]+;
L_PAREN: '(';
R_PAREN: ')';
DOT:     '.';
QUOTE:   '"';
```

Comment: The language I try to parse is really weird and STRING can't be a token. There are other rules with quotes: e.g. input `"a,"b` is not a string, it is a range between mark a and mark b, that's why I use rule with quotes instead of token.  
`NAME ('.' NAME)+ ` is not a solution, because first token not necessary a NAME, it could be wrapped expression, function call, dictionary declaration etc. `expr ('.' NAME)+` would be fine, but it also doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide an example of the failing input, and the expected interpretation?

Comment: `NAME ('.' NAME)+` fails on input `(dictionary).key` because it should be the DictFieldExpr. And `expr ('.' NAME)+` fails on input `a.b.c` because it should be one DictFieldExpr, but the result is a concatenation of VariableExpr "a" and DictFieldExpr "b.c"

Comment: I've revised the answer based upon your comments.  This still makes some assumptions, so it may miss the mark on some other input (it seems to give the right interpretation for all the samples you've provided so far.  (BTW, "The language I try to parse is really weird" is an understatement.)